# How to grant "grant create session" privilege?

Tags: oracle

How to grant the privilege of giving the privilege of creating a session to a user or role in Oracle?

Answer (score 44, accepted):

You would use the `WITH ADMIN OPTION` option in the `GRANT` statement

```
GRANT CREATE SESSION TO <<username>> WITH ADMIN OPTION
```

Comment: thanks really helpful ,but I notice it can be done without the "WITH ADMIN OPTION"

Comment: @OsamaAl-Banna - How would it be done without using the `with admin option`?  You could have a DBA create a procedure owned by a DBA (who has the `create session` privilege `with admin option`) and grant `execute` access on the procedure to you.

Comment: I was only able to login after I i typed "grant create session to osama;" however ,so if add the "WITH ADMIN OPTION" will the user become from normal user to a a DBA user ? or will have higher privileges than the normal  user ? because I don't want that

Comment: @OsamaAl-Banna - The `with admin option` lets you grant the privilege to other users.  That's not something that an average user would normally need.  But it is not something that would make you a DBA by any stretch.  The original questioner wanted to create a user `osama` that could grant the `create session` privilege to other users.

Answer (score 9):

You can grant system privileges with or without the admin option. The default being without admin option.

```
GRANT CREATE SESSION TO username
```

or with admin option:

```
GRANT CREATE SESSION TO username WITH ADMIN OPTION
```

The Grantee with the `ADMIN OPTION` can grant and revoke privileges to other users

Answer (score 1):

grant CREATE SESSION

Ref..  http://ss64.com/ora/grant.html

HTH,

Kent