# How to create user in Oracle 10g

Tags: oracle10g

I am using Oracle 10g login through user name Scott & password is tiger. I am able to create user through "create user " but "grant create session " is not working

Comment: does it helps 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19650747/how-to-grant-grant-create-session-privilege

Answer (score 0):

Did you try with `ADMIN OPTION`

```
GRANT CREATE SESSION TO <<username>> WITH ADMIN OPTION
```